# Powershell: Create local administrators remotely

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I'm looking at creating a local administrator on a handful of machines (>30). I don't really want to use GPO if I can get away with it. LAPS is a little overkill for what I need.

I found a [nice script online](https://myitblog.co.uk/powershell/script-to-create-local-administrator-account-on-remote-domain-machine/) but it only creates the user and doesn't add them to the administrators group. Can anyone see the error?

```
#Define variables
$computers = Get-Content C:\Computers.txt
#$computers = Import-CSV C:\Computers.txt | select Computer
$username = "Admin"
$password = "Password99"
$fullname = "Admin"
$local_security_group = "Administrators"
$description = "Description"

Foreach ($computer in $computers) {
    $users = $null
    $comp = [ADSI]"WinNT://$computer"

    #Check if username exists
    Try {
        $users = $comp.psbase.children | select -expand name
        if ($users -like $username) {
            Write-Host "$username already exists on $computer"

        } else {
            #Create the account
            $user = $comp.Create("User", "$username")
            $user.SetPassword("$password")
            $user.Put("Description", "$description")
            $user.Put("Fullname", "$fullname")
            $user.SetInfo()

            #Set password to never expire
            #And set user cannot change password
            $ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD = 0x10000
            $ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE = 0x40
            $user.userflags = $ADS_UF_DONT_EXPIRE_PASSWD + $ADS_UF_PASSWD_CANT_CHANGE
            $user.SetInfo()

            #Add the account to the local admins group
            $group = ([ADSI]"WinNT://$computer/$local_security_group,group")
            $username = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer/$username,user"

            #Validate whether user account has been created or not
            $users = $comp.psbase.children | select -expand name
            if ($users -like $username) {
                Write-Host "$username has been created on $computer"
            } else {
                Write-Host "$username has not been created on $computer"
            }
        }
    }

    Catch {
        Write-Host "Error creating $username on $($computer.path):  $($Error[0].Exception.Message)"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you are not actually adding the user to the group.

Here you are actually retrieving a group object, but you are not doing anything with it.

```bsh
#Add the account to the local admins group
$group = ([ADSI]"WinNT://$computer/$local_security_group,group")
$username  = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer/$username,user"
```

First you must remove the assignment to `$username`. Then you must invoke a method on the `$group` object to add the user:

```bsh
#Add the account to the local admins group
$group = ([ADSI]"WinNT://$computer/$local_security_group,group")
$computerHostName = (Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $computer Win32_ComputerSystem).Name
$group.Add([ADSI]"WinNT://$computerHostName/$username,user")
```

There is a catch here. Notice I use `Get-WmiObject` to get the hostname from the computer. When using the `Add()` method, the computer name must be the unqualified hostname. For example `server-01`, and NOT `server-01.domain.lan`

If you want to retrieve the ADSI object for the user later, I recommend assigning it to a different variable name, like this:

```bsh
$adsiUser = [ADSI]"WinNT://$Computer/$username,user"
```